# Computing the log marginal likelihood of GPR model with a LinearCoregionalization kernel

Tags: regression, tensorflow2.0, gaussian, gpflow

A InvalidArgumentError occured when I was trying to compute the log marginal likelihood of a GPR model with a LinearCoregionalization kernel, although the ELBO could be computed when the kernel was plugged into a SVGP model.

As far as I (a newbie I have to say) can see, it is because that the GPR model doesn't check whether the model is multi-output or single-output and just treat them in the same way. How can I compute it conveniently without reshaping the multi-output model into single-output one? Thanks in advance.

```
import gpflow as gpf
import numpy as np

L = 2
P = 5
N = 100
t = np.linspace(0, 1, N)[:, np.newaxis]
noise_variance = 0.01
latent_kernels = [gpf.kernels.SquaredExponential(lengthscales = 0.5), gpf.kernels.Matern52(lengthscales = 0.01)]
x = np.vstack([np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros((N,)), kernel.K(t)) for kernel in latent_kernels]).T
W = np.random.uniform(size = (P, L))
y = x@W.T+np.random.normal(0, noise_variance, size = (N, P))
coregion_kernel = gpf.kernels.LinearCoregionalization(kernels = latent_kernels, W = W)
model = gpf.models.GPR((t, y), coregion_kernel, noise_variance = noise_variance)
model.log_marginal_likelihood()
```

The error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-df8cbb66c4ca> in <module>
     13 coregion_kernel = gpf.kernels.LinearCoregionalization(kernels = latent_kernels, W = W)
     14 model = gpf.models.GPR((t, y), coregion_kernel, noise_variance = noise_variance)
---> 15 model.log_marginal_likelihood()

~/anaconda3/envs/gpflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpflow/models/gpr.py in log_marginal_likelihood(self)
     68         k_diag = tf.linalg.diag_part(K)
     69         s_diag = tf.fill([num_data], self.likelihood.variance)
---> 70         ks = tf.linalg.set_diag(K, k_diag + s_diag)
     71         L = tf.linalg.cholesky(ks)
     72         m = self.mean_function(X)

~/anaconda3/envs/gpflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    900     with ops.name_scope(None, op_name, [x, y]) as name:
    901       if isinstance(x, ops.Tensor) and isinstance(y, ops.Tensor):
--> 902         return func(x, y, name=name)
    903       elif not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    904         try:

~/anaconda3/envs/gpflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in _add_dispatch(x, y, name)
   1192     return gen_math_ops.add(x, y, name=name)
   1193   else:
-> 1194     return gen_math_ops.add_v2(x, y, name=name)
   1195 
   1196 

~/anaconda3/envs/gpflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in add_v2(x, y, name)
    478         pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
    479     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
--> 480       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
    481   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
    482   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(

~/anaconda3/envs/gpflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6604   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6605   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6606   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6607   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6608 

~/anaconda3/envs/gpflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [100,5] vs. [100] [Op:AddV2] name: add/
```

Comment: Hi @anqiyang! This is (as of May 2020) a known missing feature in GPflow, see https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1175 and https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1209

Comment: Thank you @STJ for your help! This is rather confusing, for I can implement variational sparsity approximation to MOGP but I cannot use the full model.

Comment: you can make an SVGP behave exactly like GPR if you set the inducing points to be at your data (and fix it) and use natural gradients to update the q(u) distribution as shown in the [natural gradient notebook in the docs](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/develop/notebooks/advanced/natural_gradients.html). I can expand on this in an answer if you think that'd help you!

Comment: @STJ That is a good idea! I have read that notebook, but I haven't realized that I can constrain the inducing points at the input. It might be more helpful if would expand https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/gps_for_big_data.html so that more people can see it!

Comment: if you want to help improve GPflow by adding a section on that, I'd be happy to help you figure out how to do that (both what you need to do in code and how to get it merged into GPflow)? you can join the GPflow slack (invite link is on the README.md on github) - happy to chat!